# Swift reverse guard issues

Tags: ios, swift

I have closure that may return an error. It look like:

```
session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
```

Next I want to handle error. I want to use guard statement for unwrap error, and if it exist, that show alert and return function. But how could I perform something like

```
guard !(let error = error) else { return }
```

I can't. I can check for nil and then unwrap error again, but that look kind of ugly. Or I can use if let unwrapping, but for error checking I prefer guard. So, is there any way to nicely write following?

```
guard !(let error = error) else { return }
```

Comment: I would just use an `if` in this case.

Comment: @Alexander yes but i preffer guard for check errors.

Comment: But Swift prefers that you write your code in Swift, whereas _your_ "code" is just nonsense.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You have to choose - you can use `guard` and force unwrap, or you can use `if let` and you don't have to force unwrap.  Those are your 2 options.  Swift doesn't allow your preference for `guard !let error`.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban The actual "Swifty" approach isn't possible here because of the api. The parameter should have been a `Result<(data: Data, response: Response)>` enum type, with `success(result: (data: Data, response: Response))` and `error(Error)` cases

Comment: Agreed with Alexander. See Ole Begemann's article https://oleb.net/blog/2017/01/result-init-helper/

Answer (score 9):

*Don't fight the framework*.

- If you want to use the unwrapped optional **within** the braces use `if let`

  ```
  if let error = error {
     print(error)
     return
  }
  ```
- If you want to use the unwrapped optional **after** the braces use `guard let`

  ```
  guard let error = error else {
     return
  }
  print(error)
  ```
- If the (unwrapped) content of `error` doesn't matter just check for `nil`

  ```
  guard error == nil else { ... 
  if error == nil { ...
  ```

Comment: @matt That's not true at all.  You can use the same name in a `guard` statement.  This totally compiles.

Comment: @Gereon but then i should write all of my function block in guard else block. That weird.

Comment: My comment was referring to someone erroneously insisting that this suggestion wouldn't even compile, which has since been deleted (as I've deleted my now misleading reply). Ignore this, and go with https://stackoverflow.com/a/48429279/1918561 as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask) states that when the closure is called:

- *either* `data` has a value and `error` is `nil` (if the request was successful),
- *or* `data` is `nil` and `error` has a value (if the request failed).

What you are really interested in is the data, and in the success
case you have to (somehow) unwrap that anyway.

Therefore I would check if `data` has a value. If that fails, you have an error. To avoid forced unwrapping use the nil-coalescing operator:

```
session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

    guard let data = data else {
        // The request failed.
        let message = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error"
        // Present message ...
        return
    }

    // The request was successful. 
    // Process data ...
}
```

Comment: i ended up with:             if let error = error { assertionFailure("Error occured \(error.localizedDescription)")}
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                    assertionFailure("Request error")
                    return }
                guard let data = data else { assertionFailure("No data from response")
                    return }
                guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { assertionFailure("Error occured - could not make image from response")
                    return }

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: That would *abort* the program if the request fails. In your question you said that you wanted to show an alert in the error case.

Comment: i thought that assert will abort only in debugging mode, in release it would not do anything bad.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: Yes, that is correct. So you want no alert in the released application?

Answer (score 4):

```
guard error == nil else {
    print(error!)
    return
}
```

You're safe to force unwrap error in the body since you know it's isn't a null pointer.

You're better off with

```
if let error = error {
    //handle error
    return
}
```

Comment: @Dare i dont want force unwrap.